# Get a specific number of rows from parent table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a parent table, foo, and a child table, bar, in a mySQL database.

Each row in foo may have zero or more child records in bar.

I want to get exactly 15 rows from the parent table, and all their child records. I initially did:

```
SELECT <columns> 
FROM foo 
LEFT JOIN bar 
    ON foo.a = bar.a 
WHERE <condition> 
ORDER BY <condition> 
LIMIT 15;
```

However, this will give me 15 joined rows. It's possible that the last row retrieved is a foo with multiple bar's, and that this query doesn't get all of the bar's. My requirement is that if a foo is in the result set, all of the bar's associated with that foo have to be returned as well.

What's the most efficient way to write a query that will get me 15 foo's with all of their bar's? I can think of a couple of ways of doing this, but none of them seem to be terribly elegant. (Doing a select on the parent table and then doing a second query with a join using `WHERE <foo.id> IN ...`, for example.) I'm not a DBA so I figured I'd ask the pros here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you describe:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM (
    SELECT <columns> 
    FROM foo
    WHERE <condition>     
    ORDER BY <expression-list-1> 
    LIMIT 15
) AS T 
LEFT JOIN bar 
    ON T.a = bar.a 
ORDER BY <expression-list-2> ;
```

You basically get 15 rows from `foo` according to some criteria and join the result with `bar`.

The first, internal `ORDER BY` list affects which 15 rows will be selected. The second, final list affects only the presentation ordering of the results.

The two `ORDER BY` lists do not need to be identical, although in practice they'll often be the same or the second an extension of the first, to resolve ties (how the children of the same parent are ordered).

Comment: This query will not work if there is `WHERE` condition on child table.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, can you elaborate on what you think is the problem?

Comment: Assume that there are `20` records in `foo` (parent) table and I want to select `15` records from that. Also there is `WHERE` condition on `bar` (child) table which filter out the rows. Now with the above query, I will not get `15` records every time, some of those will be missed as they will be filtered out in outer `WHERE` condition on `bar` table.

Comment: As per my above comment, though there may be still `5` records available in `foo` (parent) table, which can be joined with `bar` (child) table, which can satisfy the outer `WHERE` condition and make up the `15` records total (my limit size), but those records will never be returned at all, as there is `LIMIT` in inner query.

Comment: It's a matter of definition, if you want 15 rows from foo, with information from bar discarded, you can put the where predicate in the on clause of the left join. If you want to filter out those rows it's easiest to do with an exists clause

Comment: How exists can work here? It will cause the same issue I guess, which I am talking about. As rows will be filtered out from `foo`, they will be missed and will never return (though these rows are valid and they will fall under actual limit, but only due to inner `LIMIT` they won't be returned). I guess I am not able to put my point clearly to you in comments.

Comment: Then please ask a new question. You can use a service like:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 for the setup, and post the url or post the corresponding dml/sql. Include expected result in your question

Comment: Actually I don't have any such question, I just was pointing out limitation in above query.

Comment: The answer actually answers the op's question. If you add criteria that in a sense conflict with the original question, it is better to ask a new question.